# Use case is not getting injected for fragment ViewModelFactory

Tags: java, mvvm, rx-java2, dagger-2, clean-architecture

I am following the clean architecture with mvvm. When I injcet viewmodel factory in fragment and try to execute use case from fragment viewmodel it is giving NPE on use case. I have injected the use case as well.

Please look into the code and point out the mistake

MainModule.java

```
@Module
public class MainModule {

@Provides
LoginViewModel provideLoginViewModel() {
    return new LoginViewModel();
}

@Provides
@Named("LoginActivity")
ViewModelProvider.Factory provideActivityViewModelFactory(LoginViewModel loginViewModel) {
    return new ViewModelProviderFactory<>(loginViewModel);
}

@Provides
PasscodeViewModel providePasscodeViewModel(SetPasscode setPasscode) {
    return new PasscodeViewModel(setPasscode);
}

@Provides
@Named("PasscodeFragment")
ViewModelProvider.Factory provideFragmentViewModelFactory(PasscodeViewModel passcodeViewModel) {
    return new ViewModelProviderFactory<>(passcodeViewModel);
}
```

}

PasscodeFragment.java

```
public class PasscodeFragment extends BaseFragment<PasscodeViewModel> implements PasscodeNavigator, View.OnClickListener {

@Inject
@Named("PasscodeFragment")
ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;

PasscodeViewModel passcodeViewModel;
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    passcodeViewModel.setNavigator(this);
}

public PasscodeFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((MainApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getComponent().inject(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_passcode, container, false);
    initViews(view);
    return view;
}
 @Override
public PasscodeViewModel getViewModel() {
    passcodeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(PasscodeViewModel.class);
    return passcodeViewModel;
}
```

PasscodeViewModel.java (HERE THE SETPASSCODE IS COMING NULL)

```
public class PasscodeViewModel extends BaseViewModel<PasscodeNavigator> {

//use case
private SetPasscode setPasscode;

//data
private String tempPin;
private boolean isConfirming = false;

public PasscodeViewModel() {
}

public PasscodeViewModel(SetPasscode setPasscode) {
    this.setPasscode = setPasscode;
}

public void checkForConfirmation(String passcode) {
    try {
        if (passcode.length() == 4) {
            if (isConfirming) {
                //second attempt
                if (tempPin.equals(passcode)) {
                    //done
                    Log.e("ganesh", passcode);
                    setPasscode(passcode);
                } else {
                    //reset
                    isConfirming = false;
                    tempPin = "";
                    getNavigator().onPinNotMatched();
                    getNavigator().clearViewsForFirstAttempt();
                }
            } else {
                //first attempt
                tempPin = passcode;
                isConfirming = true;
                getNavigator().clearViewsForSecondAttempt();
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        getNavigator().wrongPinFormat();
        getNavigator().clearViewsForFirstAttempt();
    }
}

private void setPasscode(String passcode) {
//setPasscode IS NULL HERE
    setPasscode.execute(new DisposableSingleObserver<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Boolean aBoolean) {
            if (aBoolean)
                getNavigator().onPinSetSuccess();
            else
                getNavigator().onPinSetFailed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            getNavigator().onPinSetFailed();
        }
    }, SetPasscode.Params.setPasscode(passcode));

}

@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    if (setPasscode != null)
        setPasscode.dispose();
}
```

}

SetPasscode.java

```
public class SetPasscode extends SingleUseCase<Boolean, SetPasscode.Params> {

private UserRepository repository;

public SetPasscode(PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread, UserRepository repository) {
    super(postExecutionThread);
    this.repository = repository;
}

@Override
public Single<Boolean> buildUseCaseObservable(SetPasscode.Params params) {
    return repository.setPasscode(params.passcode);
}


public static final class Params {

    private String passcode;

    private Params(String passcode) {
        this.passcode = passcode;
    }

    public static SetPasscode.Params setPasscode(String passcode) {
        return new SetPasscode.Params(passcode);
    }
}
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity<LoginViewModel> implements LoginNavigator {

@Inject
@Named("LoginActivity")
ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;

LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    ((MainApplication) getApplicationContext()).getComponent().inject(this);
    loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    loginViewModel.setNavigator(this);
    initViews();
}

 @Override
public LoginViewModel getViewModel() {
    return loginViewModel;
}
```

Comment: Try to remove constructor without arguments for PasscodeViewModel , maybe you will see error. Which help you to find another problem.

Comment: Yes it throws an error if no default constructor is provided

Comment: Sounds like the default factory gets used. I'd guess you don't inject the activity anywhere and `viewModelFactory` is null, so your factory doesn't get used

Comment: @ganeshraj020794, suppose that problem is connected with that line `@Provides
PasscodeViewModel providePasscodeViewModel(SetPasscode setPasscode)` - you ask dagger to instantiate `SetPassCode` instance but he doesn't how. Do you have special method like that `@Provides
SetPasscode provideSetPasscode()`?

Comment: Yes, I am providing the SetPasscode use case in some other module!

Comment: ((MainApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getComponent().inject(this);
passcodeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(PasscodeViewModel.class);

Moved these lines to onCreate and now it's working
Problem was with the initialization of viewmodel